# Android: onDraw is too slow

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview, ondraw

I'm building a game using Android 2.2. The main game `Activity` uses a custom `SurfaceView`:

```
class GameView extends SurfaceView
```

From what I understand, the `onDraw()` method requires its own Thread to be executed. That in mind, I am planning to add a background image in `onDraw()`:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(wallpaper, 0, 0, paint);
paint = new Paint();
```

But when I execute the game, it becomes very slow. If I comment out the `new Paint()` line, the game speeds up.

Is there something I am doing wrong, or is there a solution to my problem? For example, is there a way to reduce the number of calls to `onDraw()`? Or add an `XML` attribute to my custom `SurfaceView` class?

Here's the code how I load the drawable images.

```
public Bitmap loadBitmap(String image) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        try {
            int id = R.drawable.class.getField(image).getInt(new Integer(0));
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), id);
//          bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565); 
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.e("loadBitmap", ex.getMessage());
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
```

Here's the code of the `onDraw` method.
Unfortunately, I can't post everything.

`paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);
canvas.drawBitmap(gameLevel.getBitmap(), 0, 0, paint);
// draw object(1) 320x25
// draw object(5) 50x50 each
// draw object(n) 15x15 each, estimate
// draw object(n) 50x50 each
// collision check, draw hit tile on the image sheet`

// draw game information using canvas.drawText()
timeLine++;

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is only the "paint = new Paint();" line, why don't you create the Paint object only once? When the class is first created and make it a Class variable. Then just use the object everytime you want.

Comment: actually, that line is executed once on the `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to load the background as [RGB_565](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html) instead of [ARGB_8888](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html) in case you haven't already. Otherwise there is not much you can do except switching to OpenGL

**EDIT:**

```
Options options = new Options();
options.inDither = false;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
options.inSampleSize = 1;
options.mCancel = false;
options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), id, options);
```

If that doesn't help other reasons may be:

- You drawing code is wrong
- You scale the background when you draw it
- You run it on an emulator

Comment: I'm afraid, that line returns an error. I've check the API on this the only 3 parameters of BitmapFactory.decodeResource must be (Context context, int id, Options option).

Comment: Unfortunately, It felt only like a millisecond difference.

Comment: I have placed the essential parts of the onDraw method.

Comment: And you are doing that in a background thread between lockCanvas() and unlockCanvasAndPost()? In that case i have no idea.

Comment: Yes. But isn't it because the filesize of the image a possible cause, The current filesize of the wallpaper is already around 500KB?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. In fact it should render easily at 60 frames per second if you comment everything else.

Comment: In terms of FPS. Would that be a cause?

Comment: No. Additional memory usage often increases speed. The important factors are how many pixels are drawn, what format they have and if additional operations are done (like scaling). But we covered that. To get better measuring results you might want to read this: http://d.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html